# Share object argument with sub method

Tags: jquery

I am working on JQuery plugin and got stacked in the middle. Should be so simple but I just can't find the solution;

here is what I have:

```
    (function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.myplug = function (options) {
       return this.append($("<p/>").text(option.text + " initiated"));
    }

    $.fn.myplug.ext = function () {
       //here I want read options from myplug (after running myplug first)
       //and this.attr("id") which should give me #mydiv (how do i accomplish this)
       return this.append("---" + option.text + "after initiation")
    }

    }(jQuery));


    $(document).ready(function () {
    var args={text:"myvar"};

    $("#mydiv").myplug(args);
    $("#mydiv").myplug.ext();

    });
```

html:

```
 <div id="mydiv"></div>
```

what is best practice  to accomplish these, I can't really find proper name to search this.
Thanks

**Edit**

what is ext in jquery terminology means, I named it as sub method which is not for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach what you need to the element via `.data` in the plugin init functions. Subsequent extension calls can read that data:

```
(function($) {


    $.fn.myplug = function (options) {
        var self = this;
        $(self).data('myplug', options);
        return {
            ext:function () {
               $(self).text(
                   $(self).data('myplug').title
               );
           }
        }
    }


})($);

$("#foo").myplug({title:'there'})
$("#foo").myplug().ext()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B84E9/

Extension methods should use `myplug()`, not just `myplug` in order to support proper scoping. The usual jQuery pattern is to pass an extension name as a first parameter, like `myplug('ext', ...)`.

Comment: is it ok if you show a really small example to patch it

Comment: @INgeeg: added an example

Answer (score 1):

Only functions attached to the `$.fn` object will get a correct reference to the desired `this` (the element) scope.

with your usage you are actually extending the `function` previously defined itself...

the best practice is to use the suggested plugin developement guidlines by jQuery

For example [here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/) you will find some info about it

```
// Plugin definition.
$.fn.hilight = function( options ) {

    // Iterate and reformat each matched element.
    return this.each(function() {

        var elem = $( this );

        // ...

        var markup = elem.html();

        // Call our format function.
        markup = $.fn.hilight.format( markup );

        elem.html( markup );

    });

};

// Define our format function.
$.fn.hilight.format = function( txt ) {
    return "<strong>" + txt + "</strong>";
};
```

So as you see, you can of course define a function on your plugins function, but you need to then pass the arguments to it, there is no access to the `this` scope of the element.
Alternatively you can use `call` or `apply` if you want the elements scope

```
var $el = $(".element");
$el.hilight.format.call($el);
```

Comment: so there is no way I can reference the object from ext. what about arguments